# In SSL CERTIFICATE two fingerprint SHA-256 & SHA-1

Tags: ssl-certificate, hashcode

In google SSL certificate, why two fingerprint are present.

According to my understanding there should be only one fingerprint.

**Fingerprint:**
Terms checksum, hash sum, hash value, fingerprint, thumbprint are used to describe the digital output usually in a form of a hexadecimal string which is derived from a file by means of applying a hash function (algorithm) to it.

[image]

Can anybody help me to understand

1. why there is two fingerprint?
2. Whether HASH and Fingerprint are same or different?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.why there is two fingerprint?

Just for convenience. Thumbprint is a hash value calculated over a piece of data by using particular hash algorithm. There are several algorithms that can be used for integrity check. Formerly, only SHA1 was used to calculate the thumbprint. Since SHA1 is no longer secure (the chance of getting collision is much greater than for modern algorithms) some tools claculate thumbprint by using multiple hashing algorithms.

> 2.Whether HASH and Fingerprint are same or different?

literally, the same.